# When I execute a curl script in PHP connection is initiated from client or from server?

Tags: php, curl, tcp, connection

I wanted to know if I am accessing a website using my curl script, will the TCP connection be initiated from the client who has opened the PHP page (that is my PC) or the server where the PHP page is hosted?

Is there any way to verify this ? I tried to open whatismyipaddress.com using my curl script to check what IP address it is showing but it did not show any IP address thinking the request came from a BOT.

Comment: PHP is purely server-side. Nothing it does will ever cause the client to do something, unless it's via html/javascript that gets sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

It will be from the server.  Curl is an executable binary on the server and will execute as such.  If you choose to display any output the server will push that output back down to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The client only receives HTML code generated in your server so, all happens in your server and therefore the connection is opened from your server.